# Shopify Application Proxy giving CORS error

Tags: javascript, proxy, shopify

Hello I just configured Application proxy for shopify application.

My proxy URL is: `testbypradip.myshopify.com/admin/apps/proxy`

I'm running local dev environment in with ngrok. So my origin would be `https://aa0ef495.ngrok.io`

As per shopify docs if I make get request to my proxy url I should not be getting CORS error but I am getting it.

My request looks like:

```
axios({
  url: `https://testbypradip.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/Product?upc=${query}`,
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    dispatch(requestCompleteAction(response.data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    dispatch(requestErrorAction(error));
  });
```

I've enabled CORS in express as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following. Make an endpoint in your App running in the cloud (or localhost)... reachable by ngrok or forward. You seem to have that. In Shopify App setup, create a Proxy that points at your end-point. Eg for you... app/proxy. So make that point at

```
https://aa0ef495.ngrok.io/fooblefuzz/dingbat
```

or whatever you need.

Now in your front-end code, post to the Proxy! ie)  /app/proxy

Not https://testbypradip.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/ as this is non-existant. You should not have any CORS issues as you are not doing any XHR to your cloud App. Instead, you are handling a simple POST from Shopify that you secure and act on.